# WebStorm React Native - Cannot initialize new project because directory already exists

Tags: react-native, webstorm

Hoping someone can help. Quite simply, I cannot create a new React Native project in WebStorm. I'm going through the standard 'new project' routine I've been through dozens of times before:

- File > New > Project > React Native
- Node interpreter: node `/opt/homebrew/bin/node` (v16.8.0)
- React Native: `npx --package react-native-cli react-native` (v2.0.1)

It starts to run the project create routine, then this error appears in the WebStorm terminal:

```
error Cannot initialize new project because directory "untitled" already exists.
Done
```

Can anyone shed any light on what the problem might be? I can create RN projects absolutely fine from terminal, using `npx react-native init`. I just can't create new RN projects from WebStorm, all of a sudden.

Comment: Please check your system/user temp folder. You may have a folder named `untitled` there already. Try deleting it. As far as I know (there is a chance that I'm wrong) when you are using the New Project wizard for such stuff, it first gets created in a temp folder first and then moved to the actual destination. And you may have that folder name already there from a previous unsuccessful attempt.

Comment: thanks @LazyOne. just to clarify, 'untitled' was just the example provided, because WebStorm defaults project name to 'untitled'. what ever I call the new project, I get the same message (replacing 'untitled' with the project name) I've tried with several project names.

Comment: Well, from my end right now I may only suggest the following: make a new project using  `npx react-native init` and then in WebStorm, use `File | Open` and point to the project root folder -- the IDE will make a new project from those files.